# How to get a class instance inside a lambda expression in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, lambda, inner-classes

In java when I want to get the outer class instance from an Inner class I'm writing *OutClass.this*.
In Kotlin, inside a lambda expression is there a way to get an instance of the class where the lambda expression is written if the lambda is running with a receiver?
Lets say we have the following code:

```
class Dog
{
    fun funcA () : Unit
    {
        println("Dog funcA")
    }
}  
class OuterClass
{ 
   var d : Dog = Dog()
   fun funcA () : Unit
   {
        println("OuterClass funcA")
   }
   
  fun funcWithLambda() : Unit
  {
      d.apply(){
         //place where I want to call OutClass method *funcA*
         // writing *this* will refer to *Dog* instance
         }
  }
}
```

Comment: You might consider using `also` instead of `apply` to avoid the ambiguity in cases like this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `this@OuterClass.funcA()`.

Comment: Yes I am :)   Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I'm allergic to labels, so much prefer to assign to explicitly named variables:

```
val outer: OuterClass = this
d.apply() {
    val inner: Dog = this
    outer.funcA()
    inner.funcA()
}
```

Even better is to avoid different `this` contexts entirely (obviously your example is contrived, so so is this one):

```
fun funcWithoutLambda(): Unit {
    funcA()
    d.funcA()
}
```

Comment: in your last code you don't have a lambda expression, so I don't understand how can I avoid *this* and also not to use labels

Comment: I would try to refactor to avoid the need for a label if possible. You rightly provided a minimal example, so the only way I could demonstrate that with the example was to remove the lambda completely.

Comment: @DorVak if if you could provide a gist or ask another question with a more complex example about what you're trying to achieve, I or others could possibly suggest alternatives.